# Make http call from within Javascript Express app

Tags: javascript, http, express

I am building an express (http://expressjs.com/) app which will create an API by parsing another webpage. Here is how I create my route:

```
app.get('/api/json', test.jsonParser);
```

Here is my jsonParser method:

```
exports.jsonParser = function(req, res) {
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open('GET', smhiURL);
    client.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (client.readyState == 4 && client.status == 200) {
            if (client.responseText) {
                res.render('hello', { message: 'Congrats, you just set up your app!' });
            } else {
                res.status(404).send("Page not found.");
            }
        }
    }
    client.send();
}
```

Them messag I am sending in the `onreadystatechange`is just using defult template so I can test if everything is ok but its not, I am getting `NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error`

Any ideas why this is not working? I am guessing there is some async problems but, and the `render`method is called to late.., but didn't find any better way of doing requests from within express.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/request and pipe the response out.

**Note**: XMLHttpRequest's are generally restricted to the same origin.

Comment: I will check out request. Thanks for the `Note`, I was just googling  `restricted to the same origin` Now I know why I got this error.